Are speed, scale function and killing measures of Itô diffusion absolutely continuous respect to Lebesgue measure and do have smooth derivative?
In Borodin and Salminen's Handbook of Brownian motion (MR1912205, Zbl 1012.60003), pages 16–17, they mention the fact that if the three basic characteristics (speed measure, scale function and killing measure) are absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure and have smooth derivative, then we have all the nice properties e.g. a explicit form of the infinitesimal generator etc.. One would expect that the Itô diffusion (with Lipschitz coefficient) is one of this cases since we can write the generator explicitly. Is there any proof of this?
A way of proving this I can think of is to plug the coefficients of the generator into the equations given at page 17 of the said book, calculate the characteristics explicitly and see that they are absolutely continuous. However, as the equations are written by assuming that absolute continuity holds, this is circular reasoning.
A related question as it provides example equations:

How to get speed measure $m(dx)$, scale function $s$, and killing measure $k(dx)$ of a diffusion from the infinitesimal generator?

